# How to verify the workflow steps in sharepoint desinger 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Our SharePoint 2010 workflow is now not executing as it is. We would like to verify, which step in the WF is causing the issue. Is it possible to verify the steps in the  Workflow within SharePoint designer.

(step by step verification of the steps)

Answer (score 1):

[Source :](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24047/debugging-sharepoint-designer-workflow) 
I suggest you add some logging features to the Workflow, examine the ULS logs, check that your workflow history is cleaned up properly etc.

To save you from searching around, I'll elaborate on how to do logging effectively. I use [this](http://spandps.com/2012/02/14/writing-history-events-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) method, found under Action->Core Actions->Log to History List in Workflow Designer.

I put these logs after every branch and step, and from there I write all the relevant fields to the log using the lookups. Then you just navigate to the workflow history at

http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History

and from there it should be easier to spot your issues.

Also useful is the "email" action, which essentially does the same thing but will go into your inbox and is easier to read than looking at the squashed columns of the Workflow History.